# How to restrict the default permissions in OpenShift

Tags: openshift

Our goal is to change the “default permissions” as documented in https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/admin_solutions/user_role_mgmt.html#leveraging-default-groups .
The groups `system:authenticated , system:authenticated:oauth, system:unauthenticated`
should not be able to access the API. One use case is: An ldap user who is not in the administrator group is not allowed to log into the web console. This is also how we test it.

Commands such as

```
oadm policy remove-cluster-role-from-user basic-user system:authenticated
oadm policy remove-cluster-role-from-user system:basic-user system:authenticated
```

return without error. However, we couldn’t see any effect, either. The output of `oc get clusterrolebindings` and `oc get rolebindings` remains the same, and our test user still can log on.

Are we trying the wrong commands? Or are further actions needed?

Comment: If you prevent an authenticated user from accessing the REST API, they cannot use either the web console or the command line. In effect they can't do anything and you may as well not give them an account. What is the reasoning behind this as doesn't make any sense as explained so far.

Comment: Note that applications deployed by a user do not run as that user but under a service account. The ``default`` service account applications run under has no access to the REST API. You would have to explicitly grant the privilege.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
oadm policy remove-cluster-role-from-group basic-user system:authenticated
```

So `system:authenticated` is a group, not a user. And it was the wrong command.
Thanks Red Hat Support.

Though - the cluster didn't work after running the above command, and

```
oadm policy remove-cluster-role-from-group basic-user system:unauthenticated
```

We had to revert it. I wonder if it was only the second command that wrought havoc. After nearly a week of downtime, though, the rest of the team isn't too keen on testing what happens if you only revoke basic-user from system:authenticated.

Comment: This takes provisioning from authenticated users (who aren't openshift admins, or anything else), but they can still log on: https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshift-archives/users/2016-July/msg00236.html